# After getting asp.net project from VS team server: references don't work?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, azure-devops

I just downloaded an asp.net project from my work's team server and it seems like a bunch of references aren't working. If I go to the references folder in the solution explorer many of them have a little yellow caution sign next to them and if I click on one them it says something like "this project cannot be viewed in the object browser ".  I can't find them in the add references library either. How can I correct this?

most of them are asp.net, doNoNotOpenAuth or similar web refs

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like someone added a reference to a path which doesn't exist on your system.If you right-click one of the missing references and choose Properties from the popup menu you will be able to see the path that has been set for the reference and verify if that is the case.

If your team is not already doing it, I would recommend copying third-party DLLs to a central folder under source control e.g. /lib and add all references from there to ensure that there are no path discrepancies in future.